# Updating autoincrement column in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application for record keeping. I want to ask on how to do this. 
Example I have 4 records and its id is 1 2 3 4. Then I delete record 2. What I want is I want my record to become 1 2 3 but what really happens is 1 3 4. Also if I add a new record, I want it to become 1 2 3 4 but what happens is 1 3 4 5. Please let me know how to do it. Also this row has auto increment attribute

Comment: that is the way how auto_increment works

Comment: Why would you need an identifier to change?

Comment: Is the row has auto increment attribute, you can't update

Comment: Rather than updating the index on update, you may use the index of the cursor that you're using if you want to display the index on the view...

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I am creating android application, and I use list view. I have record id = 1 2 3 4. I can query its record using the list view position. example I deleted 2, the current record that I have now is 1 3 4. I will incorrect result if I use the same method.

Comment: Looks like an instance of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you're trying to solve a problem X by rewriting identifiers (problem Y) but that's not actually a good solution to X.

Comment: The ID is *not* the same as the position (especially when you filter or sort the list). The list needs to remember the ID of each element (and as it happens, Android list widgets already can do this).

Answer (score -1):

Thats how auto-increments works. It will add the number each time you created a new row. Auto increment does not really cares number of rows deleted. In order to achieve your requirement, you can have count() option in another row. Basically it will count number of rows. You may +1 each time you insert the a new row. Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)